# Merging multiple columns with a logical where/if Python/Pandas in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, merge

Hello Stack Exchange Community,

A question

I have a data frame that I've created from a csv dump, I'm attempting to clean the data up by merging/combining the 'if other' column into the 'profession' (this actually occurs throughout the dump sometimes splitting a single question on 15+ columns/series!!)

```
'user_id' 'profession' 'if other'
 1         Professor    NaN
 2         Doctor       NaN
 3         Other(state) Voodo Priest
```

I did try something like the following but with no cigar. I'm very (few days) new to Python and programming in general so take with a grain of salt.

```
df[1] = np.where(df[1] == "Other(state)", df[1], df[1])
```

I've also seen that the .sum function could be used, but would that be appropriate to use with str values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the usual method:

```
df.loc[df['profession'] == 'Other(state)', 'profession'] = df['if other']
```

More information on `loc` accessor can be found in [Indexing and Selecting Data](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html).

**Example usage**

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 'Profession', np.nan],
                   [2, 'Doctor', np.nan],
                   [3, 'Other(state)', 'Voodo Priest']],
                  columns=['user_id', 'profession', 'if other'])

df.loc[df['profession'] == 'Other(state)', 'profession'] = df['if other']

df = df.drop('if other', 1)

#    user_id    profession
# 0        1    Profession
# 1        2        Doctor
# 2        3  Voodo Priest
```